# Отбор элементов по группе при выборе в поле ввода на форме элемента

Tags: 1с

Имеются справочники "Товары" и "Материалы". В реквизитах элемента справочника "Товары" присутствует реквизит типа "СправочникСсылка.Материал". Создаю форму форма элемента товары, на которой при выборе значения аргумента "СправочникСсылка.Материал" в выпадающем списке вариантов присутствовали только материалы, состоящие в группе "Древесина". На данный момент в модуле формы товаров:

1. Функция, возвращающая СписокВозврата с ссылками на материалы, состоящие в группе "Древесина"

```
&НаСервереБезКонтекста
Функция МатериалНачалоВыбораИзСпискаНаСервере()
        Запрос = новый Запрос;
    Запрос.Текст = "ВЫБРАТЬ
                   |    Товар.Материал.Ссылка
                   |ИЗ
                   |    Справочник.Товар КАК Товар
                   |ГДЕ
                   |    Товар.Материал.Родитель.Наименование = &Наименование" ;
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Наименование","Древесина");
    Таблица = Запрос.Выполнить().Выгрузить();
    СписокВозврата = Новый СписокЗначений;
    Для Каждого СтрокаТаблицы Из Таблица Цикл      
    СписокВозврата.Добавить(СтрокаТаблицы.Ссылка);
КонецЦикла;
    Возврат СписокВозврата;
КонецФункции
```

2. Процедура на клиенте, Устанавливающая СписокВыбора как СписокВозврата

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура МатериалНачалоВыбораИзСписка(Элемент, СтандартнаяОбработка)
    СписокВозврата = МатериалНачалоВыбораИзСпискаНаСервере();
    Элемент.СписокВыбора =  СписокВозврата; 
КонецПроцедуры
```

При запуске в режиме пользователя при нажатие выпадающих элементов списка элементы отсутствуют. Помогите решить проблему, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
СтандартнаяОбработка = Ложь;
```

И у вас очень плохой запрос

1. Добавьте вторую таблицу "Материалы". Запросы не любят обращения через точку, т.к. создаётся лишний подзапрос автоматически. Это очень сильно грузит систему, лучше заранее это исправлять
2. Получите ссылку другим способом, по возможности НЕ по наименованию, т.к. наименование товара сменят и весь ваш код уже не будет работать